# Issue With Request.Form.Get

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown list which is autopostback enabled.it contains several values.On selected_Index change event of dropdown i'm loading a gridview and it works fine.I have a Button called clearall which is supposed to change the dropdown list index to 0 and reset the gridview but when i click on the Button it will change the dropdown Index to 0 but does not reset the gridview.gridview display data of previous dropdown list selection.when i click on the button for the second time gridview is reset.

i'm using

```
dRev = Request.Form.Get("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$pnlSearchL2$i0$ddlDRevision");
```

to get the dropdownlist value and reset the gridview.looks like Request.Form.Get gets the old value on first button click.how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of using `Request.Form.Get('...')` to call `Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)` in your click event handler?